# print db values as strings with jinja and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, jinja2

I'm running two scripts in a flask application and the results are different.
The first one returns databases values as strings:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT tweet,sentiment FROM thistable 
    WHERE sentiment > 70 AND  +keyword=? ORDER BY sentiment DESC", (query,)):
    bestlist.append(row)
```

HTML:

```
{% for tweet, sentiment in bestlist %}

<h3>{{ tweet }}</h3>>
<h5>Score : {{ sentiment }}</h5>

{% endfor %}
```

Output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
Score : 94.9
Ameat valc simon chaq
Score : 88.2
```

The second one I'm fetching only one value from the list:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM thistable"):
 last_keys.append(row)
```

HTML:

```
{% for row in last_keys %}
<h3>{{ row }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Same thing..

```
{% for keyword in last_keys %}
<h3>{{ keyword}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
(u'Nasdaq',)
(u'Russia',)
(u'Samsung',)
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
Nasdaq
Russia
Samsung
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't append the whole `row` (which contains only a single column, but as a one-tuple), and you should get the result you expect:

```
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT keyword FROM thistable"):
    last_keys.append(row[0])
```

For completeness, the alternative is to explicitly access first row element when iterating in template:

```
{% for row in last_keys %}
    <h3>{{ row[0] }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```